# OSL trace(): Strange result in visibiliy analysis

Tags: osl

I would like to create a osl shader that could show the visibility of the cube surface from the cursor pos (0,0,0). So I used the trace() function like this:

```
shader Visibility(    
    point target = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    output int Hit = 0,
    output float dist=0, 
    )
{
    vector rayDir = target - P; 
    float hit_dist = 0;
    float points_dist = distance(P, target);
    int ishit = trace(P,rayDir, "maxdist",points_dist); 
    Hit = ishit;
}
```

but the result is very strange. What should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're firing a ray from `P`, the shading point, to your defined viewpoint, and you're checking for occlusion: whether anything is hit *within* the distance from `P` to the viewpoint, relying on `"maxdist"`.

There's a possibility of floating-point error, here, if your viewpoint is close to a surface, or the ray hits `P` on the way out; but I've tried fixing that with `"mindist"`, to no effect, which is a bit mysterious.

I do think, though, it might be more positive to fire *from* the viewpoint *to* `P`, where you *know* there is something to be hit, and check whether anything else has been hit on the way...

```
shader Is_Visible(
           point Viewpoint = (0),   
    output int   IsVisible = 0
)

{ 
    point hitpoint = (0);
    vector vp_to_P = (P - Viewpoint);
    trace (Viewpoint,vp_to_P);  
    getmessage ("trace","P",hitpoint);
    IsVisible = (distance (hitpoint, P) < 0.00001);            
}
```

which seems to work...

[image]

.. even then I feel an urge to wrap everything in an `if hit {}`